# All reasons that can throw IOException

Tags: java, kotlin, exception

I want to create detailed feedback for user and I want to specify all reasons/causes of `IOException`. Where can I find a list of all or at least a hint for most cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if what you're trying to accomplish is even possible since any class can throw the exception for whatever specific reason. Meaning there's no clear answer to what throws them. You can of course check every single package and class in Java and what the reason is that it throws IOException, but this is a monumental task.

This site contains every use case for IOException. You need to navigate to each package and check where specifically the IOException happens and then unederstand what the reason behind the throw is.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/class-use/IOException.html

Comment: Here is the same link - but for a [more recent version](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/class-use/IOException.html) of Java. Java 7 has not been updated [since 2015](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_7.html).

Comment: Bear in mind, also, that `IOException` has [subclasses](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/IOException.html) - and those may also have their own subclasses. I would suggest that this list of subclasses gives you a better sense of what various IO-related exceptions can be caused by, in core Java - such as `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: It's not only limited to java-defined classes, as I'm sure you (Panibo) know. But to be explicit: any code you call, directly or indirectly, can have its own reasons for throwing an IOException, a java-defined subclass of IOException, or any implementor-defined subclass of any of those.  All you can hope is that the implementors of code you choose to use have chosen rationally.

Comment: Generally though, when an exception is thrown it's a good idea to provide a value for `message` so the person debugging can see the reason why it happened. If you really want to provide the user with this information, you could display that message. But that's usually not very useful - the user doesn't need to see that technical information about why the program crashed, because it's not usually their fault (i.e. the app should prevent the crash). Any scenarios that *could be* their fault should be caught and handled explicitly, and then you can give them specific info about that specific case

Answer (score 1):

[@Panibo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76080280/139985) and the comments on it point out that is impractical (and maybe impossible) to enumerate all of the possible reasons that an `IOException` can occur.

But there are other ways to provide helpful diagnostic information to the user:

- List the *most likely* reasons to the user, based on what the I/O that the application does.  (For example, a program that doesn't do network I/O shouldn't get a networking related `IOException`.)
- Discriminate the likely subtype exceptions and report accordingly.
- Show the actual exception message to the user.
- Catch the `IOException` further up the stack.  Then:

  - rethrow it as *different* custom exceptions that provide more contextual information for generating the user error message later, or
  - report the error and terminate application immediately.